# Setting Word 2007 table style designs in code

Tags: .net, ms-word, office-interop

I am generating a Word document using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.
In that word document I am generating a table. 
I would like to set the table style to one of the nice table design presets in Word 2007+ with alternating row colors, etc.

Rather than setting all the style properties myself, is there an easier way to do this (preset name or some style snippet repository)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, I found it in the manual.

Solution:

```
            object tableStyle = WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleTableLightShadingAccent1;
            table.set_Style(ref tableStyle);
```

or in C# 4:

```
            table.set_Style(WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleTableLightShadingAccent1);
```

Comment: You can mark your answer as accepted.  Also, you can look into Open XML SDK.  It is a lot faster for Word 2007 documents.